# Tensorflow, the parameters of tf.where

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the tensorflow, and I feel confused about the tf.where function.

As we known, the function include three parameters: cond, x and y. If x and y are both not None, it will return a tensor contains elements that when cond is true return the element of x and cond is false returen the element of y.

But, I find the result of the code is confused. The code is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
sess = tf.Session()

variable_bool1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([True, False]), dtype=tf.bool)
variable_bool2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.Variable([True, False]), dtype=tf.bool)
variable_bool3 = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.constant([True, False]), dtype=tf.bool)
variable_number1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([1.0, 2.0]), dtype=tf.float32)
variable_number2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([3.0, 4.0]), dtype=tf.float32)
where_result1 = tf.where(variable_bool1, variable_number1, variable_number2)
where_result2 = tf.where(variable_bool2, variable_number1, variable_number2)
where_result3 = tf.where(variable_bool3, variable_number1, variable_number2)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

print variable_bool1, sess.run(variable_bool1), sess.run([where_result1])
print variable_bool2, sess.run(variable_bool2), sess.run([where_result2])
print variable_bool3, sess.run(variable_bool3), sess.run([where_result3])
```

And the result present below:

```
Tensor("Const:0", shape=(2,), dtype=bool) [ True False] [array([1., 4.], dtype=float32)]
Tensor("Variable/read:0", shape=(2,), dtype=bool) [ True False] [array([0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(2,), dtype=bool) [ True False] [array([1., 4.], dtype=float32)]
```

It seems that the variable_bool2 couldn't return the expected result.

Is it a problem about the difference between the Variable and constant?

Why do the variable_bool2 always return zero?

Could you explain it? Thank you very much!

Comment: what python version are you using? I just copy pasted your code into version 3.x and it shows correct results with variable reading [1., 4.]

Comment: I have two computer, both are python2.7 and tensorflow1.4. However, one of that is wrong, and another is right. It so strange.

Comment: Yea I guess you could try filing a bug report. Just curious are both running the gpu version of tensorflow?